# Integer.parseInt() doesn't parse String "id" from servlet url parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a .jsp page that lists all of my employees from a database. Next to each employee you can click on the button edit or delete, which will add an id of that employee into url param:

```
<%
            List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>) request.getAttribute("employees");
            if (employees != null)
                for (Employee employee : employees) {
        %>
        <tr>
        <td><%=employee.getId()%></td>
        <td><%=employee.getName()%></td>
        <td><%=employee.getSurname()%></td>
        <td><%=employee.getRegistrationDate()%></td>
        <td><a href="UpdateEmployeeServlet?id=<%=employee.getId()%>">edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="DeleteEmployeeServlet?id=<%=employee.getId()%>">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

When I click on 'delete', the listing is being deleted straight away and I get immediately redirected back to the list of my employees, it works well.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    int id = (int) request.getAttribute("id");
    EmployeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);
    response.sendRedirect("EmployeeServlet");
}
```

When I click on 'edit', I see te .jsp that has the url with the correct id and it asks me to provide new name and surname of my employee:

```
<form action="UpdateEmployeeServlet" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname"/><br> 
    <input type="submit"value="Save">
```

Once i click 'save', I get NullPointerException. It seems like it cannot get or parse the id parameter. Where is an error in my UpdateEmployeeServlet methods?

```
@WebServlet("/UpdateEmployeeServlet")
public class UpdateEmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public UpdateEmployeeServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Employee employee = EmployeeDAO.getEmployeeById(id);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("updateemployee.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Employee employee = new Employee((int) request.getAttribute("id"), request.getParameter("name"),
                request.getParameter("surname"), Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("registration_date")));
        int status = EmployeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("employeelist.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Comment: Paste full exception stacktrace. If there is NullPointer the problem is with `request.getParameter("id")` itself, not parsing it to `int`

Comment: In the delete case you're using `request.getAttribute("id")` and in the update case you're using `request.getParameter("id")`.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` tries to convert a `String` to an `Integer` and will throw an `Exception` if it fails to do so. Since you get a NullPointerException, it is clear that `request.getParameter("id")` is `null`. The reason of this is that your `form` does not contain any items with the `name` of `id`. Try to add a `hidden` `input` to the `form` there with `name="id"` and the correct value. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Doing form handling with Servlets is really low-level and there is no need to reinvent the wheel. You should consider using Spring MVC which has excellent support for form handling.

Having said that check the parameters of your `<form>`. You are handing over `name`, `surname` and `submit` to `doPost()`. There is no `id` given. Furthermore as pointed out already you are using `request.getAttribute("id")` instead of `request.getParameter("id")`.

You could set your object to request scope in your `doGet()`-method: `request.setAttribute("employee", employee)`. You would then access the fields of this object in your JSP. Add this to your form: `<input type="hidden" value="${requestScope.employee.id}"/>`. You should also mask your IDs (e.g. [HashIds](http://hashids.org/)) and read about [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))